# How to make entire ionic android app to run as background service?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am currently developing a todo app (android) using ionic framework which can synchronize with the pouchdb when it is connected to the internet, and also user will receive notification in background when new task has been added to the database and sync to the phone.

So if I want the user to receive the notification in background the whole app should be also running in background so that it will detect any new task sync to the phone and generate local notification to notify the user about the incoming new task.

So my question is: is it possible to make my whole cordova/ionic app or whole app.js to be running in background as a background service?

Comment: i dont know more about making whole app as background service..but you can get notifications locally before the new task time/date accordingly [look here](https://devdactic.com/local-notifications-ionic/)

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use this plugin:

https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-background-app

eventually, if you need, in conjunction with:

- [cordova-plugin-background-mode](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) to manage background mode and simple notifications
- [cordova-toforeground](https://github.com/Diusrex/cordova-toforeground) to force the to come back on foreground

Comment: I  need also how to app keep running in background when app is killed.Can u pls help me.How to use this plugin ionic 2

Comment: @beaver thanks for your answer,  will it work on both ios and android??

Comment: I haven't tested this on IoS but I see that cordova-plugin-background-app and cordova-plugin-background-mode are supported on IoS. No info about cordova-toforeground

Comment: ques is 2yr old still unsatisfied. Any one does have the solution

Comment: has anyone got this running?